# Running multiple Jmeter independent jmx tests in parallel from Java Code

Tags: java, jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-5.0

I have a Java code that executes one JMX file at a time , it also produces the results. Now , I would like to leverage the code to run multiple JMX files at the same time. Is there way I could run multiple JMX scripts (each script is different) in parallel from JAVA CODE ? Please help me with this.

Comment: Are there config elements that can't be shared across threads?  I'm curious if you curious if you can scope the inheritance at the thread group level.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is instantiating as many [Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html) objects as you need like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < how_many_threads_do_you_want; i++) {
    Thread thread = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            //your code to run JMeter here
        }
    }
    thread.start();
}
```

For more complex scenarios like waiting for completion, inter-process communication, etc. see i.e. [ExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html)

Maybe instead of trying to re-invent the wheel you might want to use ready solutions like [Taurus automation framework](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/taurus-working-multiple-jmeter-tests/)?